# How to use js library with dependencies to other libraries - angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm very new to angular 2 and I'm trying to include Miso Dataset js library in my angular 2 project.
As you can see Miso library has dependencies to other js libraries.

I already included all needed js files in my index html. But it seems I missed something else. 
How can I get it work?

https://github.com/misoproject/dataset

Comment: are you using webpack

Comment: I'm using typescipt. Error: this._initialize is not a function

Comment: Yes i'm using webpack. The error occuring when initializing the miso class. I think its because miso is using lodash to do so and the dependancy for lodash is not set properly

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that 'underscore' (_) was undefined in the js file I included in my project.
Now I used another one and everything works fine

https://cloud.github.com/downloads/misoproject/dataset/miso.ds.deps.min.0.4.0.js